# RubyMine search project for file by path

Tags: rubymine

In SublimeText 2    I can do: `cmd + t`

And then type either file names or folder names and the results displayed 
are files that either match files that match the term i'm searching for for files that are in a subfolder of the term i'm searching for, for example if I had directory structure like so:

```
/
/models
 /users
 /orders
 /products
/views
 /users
  edit.rb
  add.rb
/orders
  edit.rb
  add.rb
```

I could  do   cmd + t

And the type `"orders"` and 
the only two options that would show up would be
 the  `/orders/edit.rb`  and `/orders/add.rb` file which i could key navigate down or type add more to the search term  `"orders edit"` and the only option would be `"/orders/edit.rb"`

How can i get this same functionality in RubyMine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Navigate` | `File`, you can type the file name and directory name fragments, like `or/ed`, use the slash as the separator. Middle matching is also supported.

More details [available in help](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html).

Comment: Awesome. Actually after you said that, i see that
by doing cmd + t   and then typing   /orders/ .   i can see all the files in dir.   or  /orders/ *.rb  would show me all the rb files. This is just what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same without having to type the slash separators? I think sublime, atom, textmate and vim with some plugins do it like this. Having to type the slash makes it slower.

Answer (score 6):

*Press shift twice.*

Search for Anything with Search Everywhere in IntelliJ IDEA
http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2014/02/search-for-anything-with-search.html

Comment: His question was about RubyMine not IntelliJ

Comment: They use the same commands. Both Intellij and RubyMine are made by Jetbrains. https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1146