# Fuzzy file searching by directory?

Tags: search, intellij-idea, rubymine, fuzzy-search

I'm attempting to use RubyMine, but there's one feature that's consistently killing my productivity. I use this all the time in Sublime.

Say I have a hundred index.html.haml files strewn across my view folder. In Sublime Text 2, I can search for `/app/views/orders/index.html.haml` by hitting Cmd+t, typing "order index" and hitting enter.

But in RubyMine so far, you can't type order because directories aren't included in the search index. You can type "index.html.haml", but then I see all of the index views, and order is down around #80.

I also really prefer being able to type a portion of a file name, like the first letter of each matching file. Sublime Text 2 and PeepOpen allow you to do this easily; I'd love to have it in RubyMine.

TL:DR; **Can you search for files by directories in RubyMine / IntelliJ?**

Comment: There's a very similar question being asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093780/rubymine-search-project-for-file-by-path

Comment: However, the answer given doesn't really solve the problem. So I have multiple orders folders, and each orders folder has an index.html.haml file. Typing "orders/index" only brings up the FIRST matching file for some reason. That's bizarre. And it's still not fuzzy searching, although that's a minor complaint.

Comment: [Works perfectly](http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/7685/20130423004643.png) for me. Can you attach a sample layout that will reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the feature "Search in Everywhere" in RubyMine.

Here http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2014/02/search-for-anything-with-search.html description.